# vuejs sortable change color on drag?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, rubaxa-sortable

i am trying to implement Vue drag and drop using sortable and so far it seems to be working but how can i change the color of an element when the dragging starts?

The button outside the table element is the one whose color should change.

Here is a working codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXRWeP

```
  <v-container>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" hide-actions 
   class="elevation-2">
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
       <td >
        <v-btn class="handle" style="max-width: 28px;">
        <v-icon>drag_handle</v-icon>
        </v-btn></td>
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
      </v-data-table>
    <v-btn>Change color of this button when dragging starts</v-btn>
  </v-container>


     new Vue({
   el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
    {
      text: "",
      align: "left",
      sortable: false
    },
    {
      text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
      align: "left",
      sortable: false,
      value: "name"
    },
    { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
    { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
    { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
    { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
    { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" }
  ],
  desserts: [
    {
      value: false,
      name: "Lollipop",
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: "1%"
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: "Marshamallow",
      calories: 262,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 23,
      protein: 6.0,
      iron: "7%"
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: "Noughat",
      calories: 305,
      fat: 3.7,
      carbs: 67,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: "8%"
    },
    {
      value: false,
      name: "Oreo",
      calories: 356,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 49,
      protein: 3.9,
      iron: "16%"
    },
  ]
 }),
  mounted() {
   let table = document.querySelector(".v-datatable tbody");
   const _self = this;
   Sortable.create(table, {
     handle: ".handle",
      onEnd({ newIndex, oldIndex }) {
      const rowSelected = _self.desserts.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]; 
      _self.desserts.splice(newIndex, 0, rowSelected); 
     }
   });
  }
 })
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: @zero298 updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a function defined for `onEnd` in your `Sortable.create` call. Add one for `onStart`. Add a `color` key in `data`, and bind your button's color to it. In your `onStart` call, set `_self.color` equal to your new color; in `onEnd`, set it back to the old color.

I modified your codepen with the result: https://codepen.io/djsmedes/pen/WqRdxm

Comment: Beautiful. Simple and elegant. Thank you sir :D

Comment: And here is another pen I've made in the past that shows how you can create a directive in Vue to make this easier to reuse: https://codepen.io/djsmedes/pen/OqXjpK

Comment: Would you happen to know how to put the items back in their initial order after changing them? If you want i can create a new question

Comment: Yeah, that's going to depend on your use case. I'm guessing your actual app is not nearly identical to the vuetify examples :). In general, though, you'll have to save the state somewhere of the initial order. You could save a separate key in data that is an array with something unique about each datum (name, say, or an id of some sort) in the proper order. Or you could put an `initialIndex` key inside each datum and use that. Then you'll probably want to define a method that takes that sort order and resorts the data (desserts, in this case) to match.